# Bypass CSP rules with iframe in Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, iframe, content-security-policy, elementor

I want to include an iframe of an other website.

I simply add some HTML in a wordpress page :

```
<iframe src="https://www.website.com/page.htm" height="2000"></iframe>
```

It works very well when i'm logged as an admin in wordpress.

But when i try in incognito mode like a normal visitor i can't see the iframe due to CSP protection. I have this errors :

```
Refused to display 'https://www.website.com/page.htm' in a frame because an ancestor violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "frame-ancestors *.website.com".
about:blank:1 [Report Only] Refused to display 'https://www.website.com/page.htm' in a frame because an ancestor violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "frame-ancestors *.website.com".
```

So my question is, why it works as an admin and not as a normal visitor ? 
How can i make it works in both cases ?

Thanks

Edit with the Headers of both versions

**Header when i'm logged as an admin**

*** General ***

```
Request URL: https://www.website.com/shop.htm/
Request Method: GET
Status Code: 200 OK (from disk cache)
Remote Address: 193.164.196.82:443
Referrer Policy: no-referrer-when-downgrade
```

*** Response Headers ***

```
Cache-Control: public
Content-Encoding: gzip
Content-Security-Policy: frame-ancestors *.website.com; report-uri https://api.website.com/api/csp-report/v1/report/;
Content-Security-Policy-Report-Only: object-src *.website.com; frame-ancestors *.website.com; report-uri https://api.website.com/api/csp-report/v1/report/;
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Date: Thu, 05 Mar 2020 11:33:36 GMT
ETag: W/"1eea0-VxHcir7eEw4/DKj9v65JMo5WtVk"
Expires: Thu, 05 Mar 2020 11:43:36 GMT
Vary: Accept-Encoding
X-DataDome: protected
X-Protected-By: Sqreen
```

*** Request Headers ***

```
GET /shop.htm/ HTTP/1.1
Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_2) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/80.0.3987.122 Safari/537.36
Sec-Fetch-Dest: iframe
Referer: https://mainwebsite.com/
```

**Header when i'm not logged**

*** General ***

```
Request URL: https://www.website.com/shop.htm/
Request Method: GET
Status Code: 200 OK
Remote Address: 193.164.197.82:443
Referrer Policy: no-referrer-when-downgrade
```

*** Response Headers ***

```
Cache-Control: public
Content-Encoding: gzip
Content-Security-Policy: frame-ancestors *.website.com; report-uri https://api.website.com/api/csp-report/v1/report/;
Content-Security-Policy-Report-Only: object-src *.website.com; frame-ancestors *.website.com; report-uri https://api.website.com/api/csp-report/v1/report/;
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Date: Thu, 05 Mar 2020 11:13:20 GMT
ETag: W/"1eea0-v04Wc+e633BYpAYDMk+pKbQ2M98"
Expires: Thu, 05 Mar 2020 11:23:19 GMT
Set-Cookie: datadome=OkladZXCp6qUlASDoPL-ilsKk1AqD_IWp4LCaQQvFHI3g4Hg~cA1OMfcUALlb-_mpwd844GnUmTU6QUXMStSPePr5U~3mMOlX8hY_gstZA; Max-Age=31536000; Domain=.website.com; Path=/; SameSite=Lax
Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=15768000
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Vary: Accept-Encoding
X-DataDome: protected
X-Protected-By: Sqreen
```

*** Request Headers ***

```
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.9
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Accept-Language: en-GB,en;q=0.9,en-US;q=0.8,fr;q=0.7
Connection: keep-alive
Host: www.leboncoin.fr
Referer: https://mainwebsite.com
Sec-Fetch-Dest: iframe
Sec-Fetch-Mode: navigate
Sec-Fetch-Site: cross-site
Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_2) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/80.0.3987.122 Safari/537.36
```

The big difference seems to be it generates a cookie when i'm not logged as an admin.

```
Set-Cookie: datadome=OkladZXCp6qUlASDoPL-ilsKk1AqD_IWp4LCaQQvFHI3g4Hg~cA1OMfcUALlb-_mpwd844GnUmTU6QUXMStSPePr5U~3mMOlX8hY_gstZA; Max-Age=31536000; Domain=.website.com; Path=/; SameSite=Lax
Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=15768000
```

Comment: Is the same CSP header sent for admin and non-admin?

Comment: @HalvorSakshaug i updated the initial post with the headers when i call the iframe.